# Detecting Volume or Silence in Media Foundation

Tags: c++, audio, ms-media-foundation

I am working on developing a media player based on Microsoft's Media Foundation platform.  It is vital to the smooth operation of the program that it is able to do two things:  detect any silence at the beginning or end of a file, and perform a normalization of an audio file.  Both of these things would involve detecting "volume" or "loudness".

Based on research I've done thus far, this would involve employing the IMFSourceReader to extract the all of the IMFMediaSample objects, and then for each sample extract any and all IMFMediaBuffer objects.

Upon locking the buffer, I'll have the byte of data contained therein. How do I interpret this data in such a way as to determine "loudness", and then manipulate the data to adjust loudness?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To analyze the file, you just need to create the [source reader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd389281(v=vs.85).aspx) for the file and then read each audio-sample.

To changes values in the file, there are two options, depending on what you wanna do.

You can create an [MFT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms703138(v=vs.85).aspx) and use it in a MediaSession to change the values during playback or transcoding.

Or you can just implement the code in your programm and change the values you get from the source reader (like in the analyze mode) and write these to a [sink writer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms701626(v=vs.85).aspx). In both options you are working with the buffers of [IMFSample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms702192(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Upon locking the IMFMediaBuffer, I'll have the byte of data contained therein.  How do I interperet this data in terms of volume or loudness?  In what way might I calculate a new loudness value based on the data?

Comment: The format of the bytes in the sample depends on the Mediatype. A description for PCM can be found on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd797880(v=vs.85).aspx#PCM_Waveform-Audio_Data_Format).

Comment: So, to use an example and check my understanding, let's take the MP3 file format.  Each MP3 sample, or frame, has a header of 32 bits (or four bytes).  If I were to ignore the first four bytes of the IMFMediaSample and its buffers, and the remaining bytes in the sample would be my audio data, correct?

Comment: I would work with the raw PCM data. If you have MP3 Audio you need to decode it first. If you use the Source Reader or an MFT you can configure it so, that you get the decoded data. Then in the PCM stream you have the bytedata as described in the MSDN link in my last comment.

Comment: And so by using raw PCM data as a base, in essence you create a common denominator and eliminate the need for knowledge about the different formats, correct?